# Phony it up meaning in this sentnece

Tags: grammar, meaning

> "I hope that college students trying to decide what to do with their lives might read it and decide that it's silly to **phony it up**, and abandon their passions or even their faint interest, to become financiers." I hoped that some bright kid at Ohio State University who really wanted to be an oceanographer would read my book, spurn the offer from Goldman Sachs, and set out to sea.
> —*The Big Short: Inside the Doomsday Machine* by Michael Lewis—

The book that author is talking about is 'Liar's Poker' and it is about risky bond market creations by investment banks.

I wondered how "it" in "phony it up" works grammatically and the phrase would mean in the sentence.

I searched up the meaning of "phony up" and here is what I found.

> To create a counterfeit or illegitimate version of something.(Idioms by the free Dictionary)

And I've guessed it would mean "having false dream about working at those company creating bonds" but I'm not entirely sure.

Comment: It's not a very "typical" usage of the expression (which usually implies "deceiving" ***others***, not ***yourself***), but I think you can safely understand the cited example as equivalent to *...and decide that it's silly to **live a lie*** (i.e. - it would be foolish to deceive yourself into thinking that becoming a financier would be a rewarding career choice).

Comment: Ah, I see. I assume "it" would refer to thing that you explained in i.e.

Comment: I wouldn't go that far, no. It's effectively a "dummy" pronoun, referencing nothing in particular. Compare with similar constructions like *They're **living it up** now he's got a high-paying job* and *The cast are really **hamming it up** in this dreadful movie*.

Comment: IMO 'it' in 'phony it up' applies to their *life*. The author hopes that students will follow their passions and interests and not follow the money, thereby compromising themselves and becoming phonies, and perhaps worse: suffering from burn-out before they can enjoy the wealth they have creamed off from society.